# How to correctly find elements by class name on Python? Selenium related

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, class, debugging, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a process on [this page](https://opensea.io/), and according to its html code, after clicking  the wallet button located at the top right corner of that page, it deploys 4 main wallets to choose to log in to the page.

[image: preview1]

All of those wallets share the same class which is `elements__StyledListItem-sc-197zmwo-0 QbTKh`, and I wrote the code below in order to try to get their button names (Metamask, Coinbase wallet...), here:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://opensea.io/') #go to the opensea main page.
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button'))) #wait for the wallet button to be enabled for clicking
wallet_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button') 
wallet_button.click() #click that wallet button
wallet_providers = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "elements__StyledListItem-sc-197zmwo-0 QbTKh") #get the list of wallet providers
for i in wallet_providers:
    print(i)
```

After compiling the code above, I noticed that it didn't print anything, and it was due to the empty array of `wallet_providers`, which is very weird because I understand that by calling `find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "the_class_name")` it will then return an array containing the elements that share the same class, but it didn't do that in this case.

So, I would appreciate if someone could explain me what did I do wrong? In the end, I just wanted to manage to click on the Metamask button which doesn't always stay at the same location, sometimes it's the first element of that list, sometimes the second...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using this **CLASS_NAME** `elements__StyledListItem-sc-197zmwo-0 QbTKh` which has space in it.

In Selenium, a class name having space will not be parsed and will throw the error.

The reason why you did not get the error is cause you are using `find_elements` that will either return a list of web element or nothing.

So how to resolve this?

remove the space and put a `.` instead to make a `CSS_SELECTOR`

try this:

```
wallet_providers = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".elements__StyledListItem-sc-197zmwo-0.QbTKh") #get the list of wallet providers
```

to be honest we can have better locator than this, cause it seems these values `197zmwo-0.QbTKh` are generated dynamically.

I would rather use this **CSS**:

```
li[class^='elements__StyledListItem'] span[font-weight]
```

or this **xpath**:

```
//li[starts-with(@class,'elements__StyledListItem')]//descendant::span[@font-weight]
```

Also, you should print it like this: (this is one way but there are others as well):

**Code:**

```
driver.get("https://opensea.io/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button'))) #wait for the wallet button to be enabled for clicking
wallet_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button')
wallet_button.click() #click that wallet button
wallet_providers = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[class^='elements__StyledListItem'] span[font-weight]") #get the list of wallet providers
for i in wallet_providers:
    print(i.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Console output:**

```
WalletConnect
MetaMask
Coinbase Wallet
Fortmatic

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The locators you are using are not relative enough, and on my first inspection, I somehow didn't locate them in the DOM. So, refactored code with relative locators to make the code work.

```
   driver.get('https://opensea.io/') #go to the opensea main page.
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Wallet']"))).click()
    wallets = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-testid='WalletSidebar--body']//li")))
    for wallet in wallets:
        print(wallet.text)
```

Output:

```
WalletConnect
MetaMask
Popular
Coinbase Wallet
Fortmatic

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the class name `elements__StyledListItem-sc-197zmwo-0 QbTKh` which has **space** in it to find the elements. Actually, in Selenium we can't use the class name to locate an element/elements which have space in it. You can use CSS-Selector instead of the class name and in CSS-Selector you need to replace the spaces of the class with a (.) dot.

**OR**

You can use the parent class and then tags to point to the desired elements.
`div[class='Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0.eOSaGo'] > ul > li`